# cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener (I have implemented the LocationLister)

Tags: java, android, google-maps

When i try to run my app, the app gets crashed and in the log cat I see this error.

```
--------- beginning of crash
09-07 22:46:49.571 3479-3479/com.example.www.mytaxiapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.www.mytaxiapp, PID: 3479
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.www.mytaxiapp.Welcome cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener
    at com.example.www.mytaxiapp.Welcome.startLocationUpdates(Welcome.java:272)
    at com.example.www.mytaxiapp.Welcome.onConnected(Welcome.java:308)
```

This is my imports

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.geofire.GeoFire;
import com.firebase.geofire.GeoLocation;
import com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.zzal;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
```

And this is my method, From here the error comes, can someone help me with this please? i'm trying to fix it for hours searching the internet

```
public class Welcome extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener
{

private void startLocationUpdates() {
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED  )
    {
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mLocationRequest, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
}
```

Comment: A wild guess would be that you have accidentally imported and implemented the wrong `LocationListener` as there's also `android.location.LocationListener`.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen I have added my imports, i'm new to programming, could you tell me what i should change in my code?

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen Also in the method i have used 3rd parameter casting, since i was getting this error  "Cannot resolve method 'requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest, com.example.www.mytaxiapp.Welcome)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your imported libraries. You have imported an invalid LocationListener.
You have to import correct locationListner,

Please change

```
import android.location.LocationListener;
```

to

```
com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener
```

This will solve your problem.

Thank you.

Comment: I’m happy to help.!